# ListView Refresh with web service Response in android

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-listview, expandablelistview

**I have problem to set data into listview. Problem occurs after set message, message is set first after come 8th message from thread.**

**below is my whole code :**
**(Here is my "Activity and adapter")**

```
public class Inboxreadmsg extends ActionBarActivity {
  // <strong>Here is my global variable</strong>

  ListView lv;

  Handler h;

  Custom_Inbox_Adapter ccAdpt;

  Custom_Inbox_Adapter inadapter;
  Runnable checker;
  List<Dataset> dataset;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.messagesublistlayout);

    // map id from layout</strong>
    lv =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.readmessagelist);


    /*****************************call thread of webservice with database****************************/
    runThread();
    startHandler();
    /*****************************call thread of webservice with database****************************/


  }
  public void runThread()
  {
    h=new Handler();

    checker=new Runnable()
    {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // call webservice for fetch data
        forthread();

        h.postDelayed(checker,15000);    
      }
    };
  }
  public void forthread()
  {
    // call webservice to fetch data  
    new InboxReadChat(null, InboxReadChat.TotalMessagesOfSingleSenderUser.geturl( recipientid,InAppUserid), InboxReadChat.TYPE_GET, InboxReadChat.TYPE_RECEIVE_MESSAGE_INBOX, new ServiceHitListenerInboxChat() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(Object Result, int id) 
      {
        // After success of webservice response come this function     
        callFxnInSuccess(Result);
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(String Error, int id) 
      {
        // AfterError of webservice response come this function   
        // By this fxn set data from local database to listview
        DBvaluesSet();
      }
    });
  }
  private void callFxnInSuccess(Object Result) {
    dataset = new ArrayList<Dataset>();

    String message="",alldatetime="",time="",date="",type="";
    InboxDeliveredModel ibx=(InboxDeliveredModel) Result;

    if(ibx.getTotalMessagesOfSingleSenderUser().size()>0)
    {    
      // here webservice response data will add on local database    
      dbObject.Open();

      for(int i=0;i<ibx.getTotalMessagesOfSingleSenderUser().size();i++)
      {
        message =ibx.getTotalMessagesOfSingleSenderUser().get(i).getMessage();
        .....

        dbObject.InboxMessageAll(message,InAppUsermobile,time,recipientid,type,date);
      }

      dbObject.close();
      // After add data into database call below fxn to fetch data from database and set data in listview with adapter
      try 
      {
        DBvaluesSet();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

  }
  public void DBvaluesSet() {

    dataset = new ArrayList<Dataset>();

    try 
    {
      // By this code fetch data from local database       
      Cursor c;

      dbObject.Open();

      c=dbObject.getallmessages(recipientid);

      int countRow = c.getCount();
      int counter = 0;

      while(c.moveToNext())
      {
        msgboxitem = c.getString(0);
        // number = c.getString(1);
        timeitem = c.getString(2);
        typeitem = c.getString(4);
        datedbitem = c.getString(5);

        try {
          dataset.add(db.new Dataset(datedbitem, msgboxitem, timeitem, typeitem));
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      dbObject.close();

      // by below set data into listview into adapter 
      lv.setAdapter(ccAdpt=new Custom_Inbox_Adapter( getApplicationContext(),dataset,R.layout.row));
      ccAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Here my adapter coding...

```
public class Custom_Inbox_Adapter extends BaseAdapter{
  private Context gContext;
  private List<Dataset> gData;
  private int rEsource;

  public Custom_Inbox_Adapter(Context cnt, List<Dataset> data ,int resource){
    this.gData = data;           
    this.gContext = cnt;
    this.rEsource = resource;
  }
  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return gData.size();
  }
  @Override
  public Dataset getItem(int position) {
    return gData.get(position);
  }
  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {>            return gData.get(position).hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){

      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) gContext.getSystemService(gContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      convertView = inflater.inflate(rEsource, null);

      TextView txtReceiveMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ReceiveMsg);
      TextView txtReceiveTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ReceiveTime);
      TextView txtSendMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sendMsg);
      TextView txtSendTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.senttime);            
      TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

      // layout text chat
      RelativeLayout relSend = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.LinearReceive);
      RelativeLayout relreceive = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.LinearSend);

      // layout date chat
      RelativeLayout LinearDATE= (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.LinearDATE);

      if(position == 0){
        fetchdata= gData.get(position).getDate().trim();

        date.setText(fetchdata);
      }
      else{
        fetchdata = gData.get(position).getDate().trim();
        dd = gData.get((position-1)).getDate().trim();

        if(fetchdata.equalsIgnoreCase(dd))
        {
          LinearDATE.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        else
        {
          LinearDATE.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          Log.w("INBOX READ", "INBOX_READ_ADAPTER::::(date for position '1'):"+fetchdata);
          date.setText(fetchdata);
        }
      }

      relreceive.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      relSend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
      //txtReceiveNumber.setText(number);
      txtReceiveMsg.setText(cutmsg);
      txtReceiveTime.setText(time);    
    }
    return convertView;
  }
}
```

Comment: 862 lines of code? Are you serious?

Comment: yes, I am serious... Actually this is two class of code... Activity and adapter...

Comment: No one can read 862 lines of code. I suggest you to circumscribe your problem, and especially you should post the stacktrace of your error, or be more explicit  about what is your problem. It is hard to understand what is your problem

Comment: I have modified my code in short way... please find my problem to set data into listview.... I want talk to you that I am firstly call webservice for fetching data after that I am store whole data into database and finally I set data from database to listview with adapter....

Comment: I have problem after fetching 8th msg from webservice and set data into listview..... ordered of listview msg is not right .. i have first data duplicate..

Comment: properly entered spacing